# COREOS error on Bare Metal Server (unix socket /var/run/docker.sock does not exist)

Tags: docker, containers, coreos

I´ve installed CoreOs on BareMetal (dedicated 16GB, 4cores Atom). Docker is running and despite the fact that simple bash instructions run properly, when launching dockerui images downloaded form the hub I get the /var/run/docker.sock not found.
The sock file is present and docker daemon is running. When launching docker daemon in interactive shell I get no error from the daemon; but the error is coming from the client requesting running the image.

Comment: I had to include the volume flag:        docker run -p 9000:9000 --privileged -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock dockerui/dockerui.     It´s confusing that running it in an Ubuntu machine I did not need the flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet the container you downloaded expects the docker socket to be mounted in as a volume, so that I can control it or issue docker commands.

Check that the docs you are following don't have `docker run -v` flag in them.